# reconnect at login for davfs2

Tags: mount, automount

I have a Secure WebDAV server that I need to connect to. I was unable to connect through the "connect to server..." option in the places menu.  I was able to connect through command line by manually mounting the folder with the `mount.davfs` from the `davfs2` package.

```
~$ sudo mount.davfs https://secureserver.com/myfolder localdir
Please enter the username to authenticate with server
https://secureserver.com/myfolder or hit enter for none.
  Username: andrewredd
Please enter the password to authenticate user andrewredd with server
https://secureserver.com/myfolder or hit enter for none.
  Password:
```

It successfully connects but how can I automate this so that I can reconnect at login every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working following [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11258734&postcount=34) post with one fix: remove "***www***" from remote server name, wherever it in conf files.